# Update all fields AFTER a "save as" event in MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, field

I am creating a document template that will eventually be used as a destination for certain Excel data for customers. This will be customer facing and handled by other users than myself, so I need an automated solution.

I am using MS Word's CreateDate field to date stamp the document's creation. This will only fire on document creation using the template and after a "Save As" to rename a document built on the template. However, you have to manually update the field code after saving with a new file name.

I am an amateur at VBA, but have the following code to update fields (comes from Greg Maxey):

```
Public Sub UpdateAllFields()
  Dim rngStory As Word.Range
  Dim lngJunk As Long
  Dim oShp As Shape
  lngJunk = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      On Error Resume Next
      rngStory.Fields.Update
      Select Case rngStory.StoryType
        Case 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
          If rngStory.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
            For Each oShp In rngStory.ShapeRange
              If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update
              End If
            Next
          End If
        Case Else
          'Do Nothing
        End Select
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Get next linked story (if any)
        Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
      Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

I know of the BeforeSave event, but Word does not have an "after save" event, and I don't know how to trigger the code. Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into many Word menu commands by reusing the command name as a macro. The most fool-proof way to do this is with these steps:

1. In Word, choose **Developer>Macros**.
2. Set the **Macros in** dropdown to **Word commands**.
3. In the list of commands, choose **FileSaveAs**.
4. Switch **Macros in** back to the template that your macros are in.
5. Click on the **Create** button. Word creates a new macro in your template that contains only the line:

```
Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show
```

After that command add the commands you need to run after the save.

Then when the user does a save as, they see the dialog and save the file, then your VBA runs.

Once you get the idea, you don't have to go through the whole procedure. As long as you know the VBA names for the built-in dialog and the Word command, you can just type them in using the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this looks to be useful for other macros and I didn't know about it. Unfortunately this didn't work when I tested it - I still needed to manually update the fields after Save As. Perhaps this is because the dialog box doesn't trigger the actual Save event? Any ideas?

Comment: Closing the dialog triggers the save as. Please post the current code you are using to update the field.

Comment: Ok, apologize for the delay in reply. So the code works perfectly as long as I trigger it by clicking on "run Macro" in the Developer tab - it opens the Save As dialog box and then runs the code on save. However when I go through the normal File > Save As process no fields update. My code is exactly what I posted in the original post with the addition of the Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show line at the beginning. Thank you again

Comment: This is a known good technique I've used many times. Perhaps instead of adding the dialog statement to your existing code, you could follow the steps I posted to see if it makes a difference. Here is Microsoft's page on the subject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/modifying-a-word-command

Comment: Clarification -- I am using Word 2013. I did go through your steps as written, and will retry from scratch following your steps

Comment: Reporting back here - no difference made. I tried wiping all macro code in the current template and following the steps from scratch, creating a new template and doing same. Nothing.

I just read in an MSN support thread that as of Word 2013 Going File > Save As does not call the actual FileSaveAs command? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-word/word-2016-save-as-command-trigger-vba/6758bd4f-d3e6-4110-addf-f19ea671b7ca?auth=1

Comment: Thanks for posting that link. There are several messages that are hidden once an answer is marked on that site. Below the answer, click on Replies, then scroll down to Jay Freedman's first reply where he explains adding a class module. That should get it working.